# How to show upload percentage when uploading video to firestore react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

How do you show the upload progress percentage when uploading to firestore in react native? I already know how to upload the video, but just need to show the progress.

code to upload

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
require('firebase/firebase-storage')

export const saveMediaToStorage = (media, path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(path)

    fetch(media)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => fileRef.put(blob))
        .then(task => task.ref.getDownloadURL())
        .then(downloadUrl => resolve(downloadUrl))
        .catch(() => reject())
})
```

this code calls the code above to save the data aswell as the media

```
export const createPost = (filter, location, description, video, thumbnail) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let storagePostId = uuid()
    let firestorePostId
    let curTime = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    let allSavePromises = Promise.all([
        saveMediaToStorage(video, `post/${currentUserId}/${storagePostId}/video`)
        saveMediaToStorage(thumbnail, `post/${currentUserId}/${storagePostId}/thumbnail`)
    ])

    allSavePromises
        .then((media) => {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection('post')
                .add({
                    creator: currentUserId,
                    media,
                    description,
                    location,
                    likesCount: 0,
                    savedCount: 0,
                    commentsCount: 0,
                    creation: curTime,
                    filter: filter
                })
                .then(docRef => {
                    firestorePostId = docRef.id

                    firebase.firestore()
                        .collection('locations')
                        .doc(location.geohash)
                        .collection('posts')
                        .add({
                            postId: firestorePostId,
                            creator: currentUserId,
                            geohash: location.geohash,
                            dateAdded: curTime,
                        })
                    })
                .then(() => resolve())
                .catch(() => reject())
        })
        .catch(() => reject())
})
```

this will be in the main that will be used to run the two codes above and right now request running is used to show that the video is uploading, but I dont know how to show the progress

```
const [requestRunning, setRequestRunning] = useState(false)
const handleSavePost = () => {
        setRequestRunning(true)
        createPost(filterTypes, location, description, props.route.params.source, props.route.params.sourceThumb)
            .then(() => navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop()))
            .catch(() => setRequestRunning(false))
    }


if (requestRunning) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.uploadingContainer}>
                <ActivityIndicator color='red' size='large' />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to monitor and log the progress of the upload operation is described in the Firebase documentation on [monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress). I recommend checking out the example code from there.

```js
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```